# My log in code seem not working properties

Tags: json, angularjs, http

I want to get the file from json and compare them with the textbox that I get from the input form, but my code seems not working properties. I am very new to angular and this is my first try project not for work.

//This is JS file

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('routerApp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $location) {

        $scope.loginUser = function () {
           $http.get('data.json').then(function(data){
               $scope.users = data;
               var usr = $scope.usr;
               var pwd = $scope.pwd;
               if(data.username == usr && data.password == pwd){
                   $location.path('/laptop');
               }
               else{
                   alert("Username or password is incorrect");
               }
           }); 
        };
    });
})();
```

When I click login button it always true even I didn't input anything

Comment: Check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns. The content of your JSON will be in the data property of the response. In your case data.data. Also check if data.json contains an array (later stored in $scope.users) In that case you must perform a search on that array rather than access the unexistent properties username and password.

Comment: Which line is giving you unexpected results? The problem can be discovered with simple debugging techniques.